# chrome extension to fill forms, seems right by code, but nothing happens when button is clicked in the extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Everything seems fine through the code, but extension does nothing when I try and click the button.

I have already tried implementing content scripts. One more question, where should I get the Id in the document.getElementById(). I am trying to make a form filler on a certain webpage, so I am inspecting the first name on the web page text box and getting the id from that.

manifest-

```
{
 name : "Form Filler",
 "version": "1.0",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "description": "fill forms",
  "content_scripts": [{
     "matches" : ["https://boards.greenhouse.io/vimeo/jobs/1792324"]
      "js" : ["popup.js"]
}],
"browser_action": {
    "default_popup" : "popup.html"   
}
}
```

popup.html-

```
<html>
<body>
<button type="button" id="fill">Fill</button><br>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<body>
</html>
```

popup.js-

```
function Fill(){
   chrome.tabs.executeScript({file: "content.js"})
};

 document.getElementById("Fill").oneclick = Fill;
```

content.js-

```
document.getElementById("first_name").value = "somefirstname"
```

Comment: `oneclick` should be `onclick`

Comment: still does not work, getting error cannot set property of onclick to null, could my ID's be wrong?

Comment: Yep, id is case-sensitive so it should be `"fill"`, not `"Fill"`.

Comment: could the id be wrong for content.js

Comment: any other reasons why this could be failing

Comment: The content script runs in the web page. But the browser_action popup is a separate extension page, not related to the web page in any way.

Comment: how can I make them relate, when the button is clicked from the html, there is a change on the web page

Comment: See [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)

Comment: i did, i declared content scripts

Comment: You're using the same script both in the popup and in the web page, which doesn't usually make sense because these are totally separate pages. The answer I've linked explains how to organize communication.

Comment: what do you mean same script?

Comment: The main issue is connection to the website, not the code itself

Comment: could there be an error in, document.getElementById("first_name").value = "somefirstname". I don't want to be mistaken, this should find the value of first_name in the html of the sight, and replace it with some first name right.

Comment: You load popup.js in the web page (as a content script) and in the popup (as a normal script).